# Python/Pandas Dataframe replace 0 with median value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, median

I have a python pandas dataframe with several columns and one column has `0` values. I want to replace the `0` values with the `median` or `mean` of this column.

`data` is my dataframe
`artist_hotness` is the column

```
mean_artist_hotness = data['artist_hotness'].dropna().mean()

if len(data.artist_hotness[ data.artist_hotness.isnull() ]) > 0:
data.artist_hotness.loc[ (data.artist_hotness.isnull()), 'artist_hotness'] = mean_artist_hotness
```

I tried this, but it is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and add parameter `skipna=True` to [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html) instead `dropna`. Also need change condition to `data.artist_hotness == 0` if need replace `0` values or `data.artist_hotness.isnull()` if need replace `NaN` values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'artist_hotness': [0,1,5,np.nan]})
print (data)
   artist_hotness
0             0.0
1             1.0
2             5.0
3             NaN

mean_artist_hotness = data['artist_hotness'].mean(skipna=True)
print (mean_artist_hotness)
2.0

data['artist_hotness']=data.artist_hotness.mask(data.artist_hotness == 0,mean_artist_hotness)
print (data)
   artist_hotness
0             2.0
1             1.0
2             5.0
3             NaN
```

---

Alternatively use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), but omit column name:

```
data.loc[data.artist_hotness == 0, 'artist_hotness'] = mean_artist_hotness
print (data)
   artist_hotness
0             2.0
1             1.0
2             5.0
3             NaN

data.artist_hotness.loc[data.artist_hotness == 0, 'artist_hotness'] = mean_artist_hotness
print (data)
```

> IndexingError: (0     True
>   1    False
>   2    False
>   3    False
>   Name: artist_hotness, dtype: bool, 'artist_hotness')

Another solution is [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with specifying columns:

```
data=data.replace({'artist_hotness': {0: mean_artist_hotness}}) 
print (data)
    aa  artist_hotness
0  0.0             2.0
1  1.0             1.0
2  5.0             5.0
3  NaN             NaN
```

Or if need replace all `0` values in all columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'artist_hotness': [0,1,5,np.nan], 'aa': [0,1,5,np.nan]})
print (data)
    aa  artist_hotness
0  0.0             0.0
1  1.0             1.0
2  5.0             5.0
3  NaN             NaN

mean_artist_hotness = data['artist_hotness'].mean(skipna=True)
print (mean_artist_hotness)
2.0

data=data.replace(0,mean_artist_hotness) 
print (data)
    aa  artist_hotness
0  2.0             2.0
1  1.0             1.0
2  5.0             5.0
3  NaN             NaN
```

If need replace `NaN` in all columns use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
data=data.fillna(mean_artist_hotness) 
print (data)
    aa  artist_hotness
0  0.0             0.0
1  1.0             1.0
2  5.0             5.0
3  2.0             2.0
```

But if only in some columns use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
data['artist_hotness'] = data.artist_hotness.fillna(mean_artist_hotness) 
print (data)
    aa  artist_hotness
0  0.0             0.0
1  1.0             1.0
2  5.0             5.0
3  NaN             2.0
```

Answer (score 19):

use `pandas` `replace` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0], 'b': [2,3,4,6,0,5,3,8]}) 

df 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  4  6
4  0  0
5  0  5
6  0  3
7  0  8

df['a']=df['a'].replace(0,df['a'].mean())

df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  4  6
4  1  0
5  1  5
6  1  3
7  1  8
```

Answer (score 2):

Found these very useful, although [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) is really slow (not sure why).

I did this:

```
df.loc[ df['artist_hotness'] == 0 | np.isnan(df['artist_hotness']), 'artist_hotness' ] = df['artist_hotness'].median()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data['artist_hotness'] = data['artist_hotness'].map( lambda x : data.artist_hotness.mean() if x == 0 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think below code will solve your problem in one line.

```
    data['artist_hotness'] = data['artist_hotness'].replace(0, 
    data['artist_hotness'].mean())
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.